# Subida de profile pic en dashboard, error en ASHX - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, fileupload

Quiero subir una imagen y que esta se muestre dentro de un div.

[image: imagen 1]

Pero cuando subo la imagen, me indica que se subio correctamente pero no se muestra  la imagen.

[image: imagen 2]

Abro la direccion de la imagen y me muestra esto:

[image: Imagen 3]

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

ASPX:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
```

ASPX.CS

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UserSessionID"] != null)
            Image1.ImageUrl = "HttpHandler.ashx?ID=" + Session["UserSessionID"].ToString();
        else
            Session["UserSessionID"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        Image1.ImageUrl = "HttpHandler.ashx?ID=" + Session["UserSessionID"].ToString();
    }
    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
                Session["UserSessionID"] = Session["UserSessionID"] + ext;
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + Session["UserSessionID"]);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                Image1.ImageUrl = "HttpHandler.ashx?ID=" + Session["UserSessionID"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

httphandler.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="HttpHandler.ashx.cs" Class="SyncfusionASPNETApplication8.HttpHandler" %>
```

httphandler.ashx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string imagePath = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];

    // split the string on periods and read the last element, this is to ensure we have
    // the right ContentType if the file is named something like "image1.jpg.png"
    System.IO.FileInfo imageFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(context.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + imagePath);
    bool fileExists = imageFile.Exists;
    if (fileExists)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" + imageFile.Extension;
        context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath(imagePath));
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath("NoImage.jpg"));
    }
    context.Response.Write(imagePath);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

}

Mi problema es ese, y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

He intentado de todo, pero no funciona nada.

Comment: Pareciera que 'SyncfusionASPNETApplication8' no es tu namespace en el archivo .cs